# PIC18F97J60 Ethernet performance

Tags: ethernet, pic

Does anyone else use the PIC18F97J60 Ethernet capability? If so what kind of RX/TX performance is typical for that chip? I was running the TCPPerformanceRX/TX applications provided as part of the Microchip TCP/IP stack and getting between 1500-2000 bytes/sec TX and 60-80 bytes/sec RX. Receive seems way slower than it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used the same chip from the same family (18F67J60) and I don't have quantitative data from its use, but your values are definitely significantly lower than I have seen (certainly my RX is many times faster than that).

One application I use with the chip is do bootloading via TFTP and I can receive information on the PIC at ~20k/sec or so.  I would look at how you're setting up your ethernet.  Perhaps the registers are set up incorrectly?  Is your ethernet hub bad?  I would try importing one of the basic examples from microchip (its on the C: in the microchip folder and has a few example applications) and see how fast its going.  Maybe use the Wireshark application to see the data going back and forth, maybe that will give you a clue as to whats happening.

Comment: +1 for Wireshark! I just downloaded it and I’ve started to check out the packets to see if I can find any hints as to what could be wrong.

Comment: I love packet sniffers. It is my favorite form of robot porn. Second is schematics.